# Translate 'operational' and 'strategic' in Chinese

Tags: translation

How to translate 'operational' and 'strategic' in Chinese?
The best match I've found is '操作' and '战略', but would they be correct in a phrase like:

> Operational and strategic business decisions

**EDIT**

Context the word pair to be used in:

> BI can be used to support a wide range of business decisions ranging from operational to strategic

Comment: iciba has plenty of example sentences and definitions for "operational", as well as "strategic"  爱词霸为两个形容词提供大量的例句和定义

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most appropriate translation for "operational" is 运营. for example, “the day-to-day operational aspect of the business” can be translated as 公司每天运营方面。。。or for example Chief Operating Office is commonly translated as 首席运营官

Answer (score 1):

Those two words typically come up together in a business context.

operational  运营的
strategic  战略的

Remind: these are only in a business or similar context. In others, the translation does subtly change a little.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "operational".  I've often heard a distinction made between "strategic" and "tactical" decion-making.  If you are looking for that kind of distinction, 操作 may not be a good choice. One way I've heard people try to express it is 策略 and 戰術. It doesn't feel very natural to me, but in some cases it might work: 布局要有策略，進攻要有戰術 or something like that.  Have you tried looking in 孫子兵法? Bet he has some way of expressing this.

Comment: Thanks, but 策略 is a noun, more like 计划，计策，as you see

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @S.Rhee, I've found an answer:

- 作战 - operational (in context of time)
- 战略 - strategic

**EDIT**

As it was mentioned by @MasterSparkles 作战 has military tingle, so perhaps it's not good to use in business context.

Comment: please accept your own answer if you found yours helpful

Answer (score 0):

In a business context, 作战 seems inappropriate for "operational", unless you are really wanting that military tinge.  I would suggest 业务 as a counterpoint to 战略 as in the following from [http://wiki.mbalib.com/wiki/战略管理](http://wiki.mbalib.com/wiki/%E6%88%98%E7%95%A5%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86):

> 业务层战略着眼于企业中某一具体业务单元的市场和竞争状况，相对于总体战略有一定的独立性，同时又是企业战略体系的组成部分。
>
> An operations-level strategy focuses on the market and competitive status of a certain, specific operational unit within the enterprise, and has a certain indepdence vis-a-vis an overall strategy, while at the same time forming a part of the enterprise's strategic apparatus.

Comment: Ok, I'm agree about military tinge of 作战, but 业务 is not the word we need here "operational - happening in the nearest future", 业务 sounds more like "business, occupation"

Comment: it can mean that- it can also mean operation/al . Can you help us out with context?

Comment: Yes, context is added

Comment: I still think 业务  is your best choice: m.jiemian.com/article/294778.html - 持股方并不参与决策，战略决策由3位董事决定，而所有业务方面的决策都由陈旭东和他带领的团队来完成，“神奇工场我本人也出了一部分钱，完全是 ...